# multiple conditions in a vba do while loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that can be any where from 5 to hundreds of pages that provides patient information based upon lab tests.  Each patient record is separated by underscores with a check box at the end. "___________|____|"  Example:

LastName,First  Patient Number   Unit   ANC    02  ####  2/23/2017 15:56
 BLOOD
   GLU-ANC  416 mg/dL    H*  REf. RAnge: 60-100        Critical 50-399
COMMENTS: Patient detail information and notes from the doctor show up 
here   and can be very flexible... 
           More clinical info etc.
_________________________________________________________________________|____|
LastName,First  Patient Number   Unit   CH  1234  2/23/2017 15:56
 SERUM
   TROP I  54 mg/dL    H*  REf. RAnge: 60-100        Critical 50-399
COMMENTS: Patient detail information and notes from the doctor show up 
here   and can be very flexible... 
           More clinical info etc.
_________________________________________________________________________|____|
LastName,First  Patient Number   Unit   ANC      1234  2/23/2017 15:56
 FECES
  FIT  POSITIVE   H*  REf. RAnge: "NEG"-""60-100        Critical: REPORT
COMMENTS: Patient detail information and notes from the doctor show up 
here   and can be very flexible... 
           More clinical info etc.
_________________________________________________________________________|____|

If I find certain value, for example ANC or FIT in the patient record, I can skip these records when I review the printed report. So I want to replace the underscore check box with |SKIP|.

I can do this easily with a for next loop but the problem is I don't every know how many "ARTERIAL BLOOD" or "ANC" or "FECES FIT" that will show up on a given report.  So I have been trying to figure out how to replace my For Next loop with a Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True statement.

But have tried many variations and cannot get the syntax right.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my working For Next Loop

```
Sub xSimplefind()
Dim vtext As String
   vtext = InputBox("Text to find") 'Here I enter 1st search value ie. "ANC"
  For i = 1 To 7
  With Selection.Find
  .Execute FindText:=vtext
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
 End With
'Once I find that first item, I then look for the very next "|_____|"
  With Selection.Find
  .Execute FindText:="|____|"  'TypeText overwrites Selected text.
  Selection.TypeText Text:="|SKIP|"
 End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you need, but an example will hopefully set you on the right track:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MultiFind()
    Dim valueToSkip() As String
    valueToSkip = Split("ANC,FIT,ARTERIAL BLOOD,FECES FIT", Delimiter:=",")

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    found = False
    For Each value In valueToSkip
        With Selection.Find
            Set result = .Execute(FindText:=value)
            If Not result Is Nothing Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next value

    If found Then
        '--- add |SKIP| here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!  I tried the code with the edition of my paste, but the system stops at the "Set result = .Execute (FindText:=value) line.  I've tried numerous variations and can't seem to get past that point.  Any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code works if anyone else needs to do something like this...
Thanks for the input and help from others!!
= = = = = Solution Found = = = = = = = = = 
Sub test()
     Dim vtext As Variant
     For Each vtext In Array("Arterial", "ANC", "FIT", "PREVIOUS")
         Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

```
     '
     'Inner loop to check every line
     '
     While True
         Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
         Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
         With Selection.Find
             .Text = vtext
             .Replacement.Text = ""
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindContinue
             .Format = False
             .MatchCase = False
             .MatchWholeWord = False
             .MatchWildcards = False
             .MatchSoundsLike = False
             .MatchAllWordForms = False
         End With
         Selection.Find.Execute
         With Selection.Find
             .Text = "|"
             .Replacement.Text = ""
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindContinue
             .Format = False
             .MatchCase = False
             .MatchWholeWord = False
             .MatchWildcards = False
             .MatchSoundsLike = False
             .MatchAllWordForms = False
         End With
         Selection.Find.Execute
         Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
         If Selection.Text <> "|SKIP|" Then
             Selection.Text = "|SKIP|"
         Else
             GoTo DoNextWord
         End If
     Wend
```

DoNextWord:
     Next vtext
 End Sub